# Where to declare the ArrayList, if I want dynamically to fill it

Tags: java, arraylist, server

I have a Java Server, I want to store all IP, which send requests to Server, because I want to check, if user was here already, and if he was I want to send him another message.

There method **sendStaticResource** at the bottom should do it.

For this purpose I want to use **ArrayList ips**, which I will check every time, when request comes. My problem is that the values(IPs) won't be store - each time request is made, the old IP disappears ( so the length is always 1).

So the question is - where and how could I initialise the ArrayList, so each time request is made, ip goes in the Arraylist and the old won't disappear

```
public class Response {
      Request request;
      OutputStream output;

      ArrayList<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();


      public Response(OutputStream output) {

        this.output = output;
      }

      public void setRequest(Request request) {

        this.request = request;
      }


      public String getIp() {
        InetAddress thisIp = null;
        try {
           thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.toString() );
        }
        return thisIp.getHostAddress();
      }

      public void content(String header, int contentLength, String msg ) throws IOException  {
        System.out.println(msg);
        String message  = "HTTP/1.1" + header + "\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: "+ contentLength + "\r\n" +
                "\r\n" +
                "<h1>" + msg + "</h1>";
        try {
          output.write(message.getBytes());
          output.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
      }

      public void sendStaticResource() throws IOException {
          if(request.getUri().equals("/")) {
            content("200 OK", 20, "Hello world");
            ips.add (getIp());
            System.out.println(ips.size());
          } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: I would use a Set for this since you are only keeping track if an item exists.  Use a Map if you want to do more than just keep track of it's existence.  You would have to define a static one and use ConcurrentHashSet to make sure you have a synchronized collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that each a request comes in you create a new `Response` object. Since the `ips` list is an instance member of the `Response` object, each time you create a new instance of it you also create a new list of `ips`.

If you want to have a list of strings storing all the ips of the requests you have received, I suggest you modify your code in such manner that the ip list is a static field of the `Response` object.

This way you'll end up with something that is shared between all the objects of the `Response` class and not something unique to each instance. For more information I would suggest to  check on the differences between instance and static members of a class. For more you can check here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Finally a small hint concerning code style and best practices revolves around this line:

`ArrayList<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();`

I would strongly suggest to user something like this:

`List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();`

In my honest opinion it's much better to code to and interface rather than the concrete implementation.